# Trying to play a video from internal storage on device wont work. Permissions issue? man,xml,java included

Tags: java, android, video, view

**I have attached *hierarchy image,manifest, xml, java***

I have images and video in my internal storage.  In 1 activity of my application, i show images.  It works.  In the other activity, i show video.  All i get is "Sorry, this video cannot be played" and returns:

```
10-11 12:58:50.889: E/MediaPlayer(23497): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

It seems like it might be a permissions issue, as if the video is on /mnt/sdcard/..   it will do exactly as it was told.  These videos are not to be altered so someone decided to place them into internal storage, located at /data/data/....

I figure it might be due to a way i was referencing the image but this issue shouldnt be called as it is the same app.  Is Is there a special Manifestflag i need or something to read video from /data/data/...?

Layout of Applcation:

```
                 -----------------------------------------
                 |            Application                |
                 |           _/         \_               |
                 |   ImageActivity     Video Activity    |
                 -----------------------------------------
```

Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pl_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bentley.cordova.plugins.MediaPlaybackActivity" 
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
</application>
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
path = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("path_name"); 
//path looks like:   /data/data/com.XXXXX.viewer/folder/video.mp4
setContentView(R.layout.media_playback_video);
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very important what codec was used to encode this videos, tries with other videos and see if this is the issue. by default android video view can not play any type of video.

Comment: if it is recorded by the device, it should be playable by said device.  There are chances that yes, data would be imported, but currently all the videos are from the individual device.